# How to find videos on Facebook

Tags: video, search, facebook, search-engine

How can I find videos on Facebook like we search on Youtube?

Is there any website or an app in Facebook that allows to do so?

Is it possible to find videos using graph search?

Comment: Please read the facebook tag you included. You are asking an off-topic question. Websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress are off topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [WebApps.SE].

Answer (score 1):

You can search for videos using various search parameters in the URL string. For example, this search query will return videos posted by friends of your friends:

```
https://www.facebook.com/search/me/friends/friends/videos-by/intersect/
```

while this one will return videos where your friends are tagged:

```
https://www.facebook.com/search/me/friends/videos-tagged/intersect/
```